# How to enable a makefile to escape wildcard braces

Tags: shell, makefile

Consider following makefile snippet:

```
CXX := g++

test := sort{1..4} # i.e. sort1 sort2 sort3 sort4

#all: $(test)

$(test): %: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -o $@ $<
    
clean:
    rm -f $(test)
```

where `sort1`, `sort2`, `sort3`, and `sort4` are expected to be the output (executable) files. However, when executing in shell:`make $test` or `make clean`, the wildcard `{` `}` seem NOT to expand, and the command can't remove those four files.  How can I expand wildcard `{` `}` in a makefile?

Additionally, I've noticed a interesting phenomena: first let's use the non-expanded version (before I figure out above problem), with `test := sort1 sort2 sort3 sort4` instead of `line 3`. When there is no target using the variable `test` (i.e. comment `line 5`), then if we try: `make $test` we will memerly compile  `sort1`. However, when we try to use a target with prerequisites on this variable, for example, uncomment `line 5`, then `make $test` is equivalent to `make all`, thus generating four output files. How to explain this?

Thanks in advance for taking time for this trivial question, but it would mean a lot to me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Although `make` does not expand sequence expressions internally, a shell that does expand them could be run from `make`; try the examples below.

Running `make $test` from a shell likely finds the shell variable `$test` not set and shell variable substitution yields nothing, so the command-line is reduced to only `make`, which goes about building the first target. When the `#all:` line is commented-out, `make` finds `sort1` as the first target (provided `test` is set as expected); after removing the comment from `#all`, the first target will be `all`, so then `make` would handle the provided prerequisites.

```
CXX := g++

# straight assignment
test := sort1 sort2 sort3 sort4
$(info plain: "$(test)")

# foreach built-in
nset := 1 2 3 4
test := $(foreach n,$(nset),sort$(n))
$(info foreach: "$(test)")

# run a shell for sequence expression
test := $(shell echo sort{1..4})
$(info shell: "$(test)")

.PHONY: all
all: $(test)

$(test): %: %.cpp
        $(CXX) -std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -f $(test)
```

Comment: Note that `echo sort{1..4}` is not a POSIX standard feature.  It's a bash feature (and probably other advanced shells).  Make always run `/bin/sh` as its shell.  So, that feature will not work on systems (like Debian and Ubuntu) where `/bin/sh` is not bash but is instead a smaller, faster POSIX shell like dash.  So, this is not a portable solution.  You could use `$(shell /bin/bash -c 'echo sort{1..4}')` to be portable (to systems that have bash installed) if you really wanted to...

Comment: How about `test := $(addprefix sort,1 2 3 4)`?